# Fizz, Buzz, or FizzBuzz?

Tags: beginner, programming-challenge, r, fizzbuzz

I was messing around online at work the other day when our phone systems went down. I came across the `R` programming language. Now I'm not guru with programming by any means but I like to mess around with different languages here and there, I believe it helps me to become a better programmer. So I decided that I would try to solve the `fizzbuzz` challenge in `R` for those of you that don't know what `fizzbuzz` is:

> Write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of the number and for the multiples of five print "Buzz". For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print "FizzBuzz"

This is the first thing I've ever written in `R` and I would like to have some critique done on what I've accomplished so far:

```
fizzBuzz = function(range, x, y){
    for (i in seq(1, range, by=1)){
        if (i %% x == 0 & i %% y == 0){
            print('FizzBuzz')
        }
        else if (i %% y ==0){
            print('Buzz')
        }
        else if (i %% x == 0){
            print('Fizz')
        }
        else{
            print(i)
        }
    }
}
fizzBuzz(100, 3, 5)
```

Some key things I'd like to focus on, per norm feel free to critique everything;

1. Is it a little bit over kill to put this all in a function, obviously I could do it simply without the function, but is this considered good practice in `R` to put your solutions inside of functions? I only ask because I looked around at peoples code and didn't see very many functions in it.
2. Are there easier ways to create the range? I feel like `seq(from, to, by=1)` is a little harder to understand then `range(from, to)`

Comment: In ref to 1. I think functions are good solutions (especially for this kind of problem), and good stuff if you can write them. However many R users (including myself) come from no programming experience at all, and so we write things without writing our own functions if we can help it. My solution to the problem, unless I was aiming to write customer functions, would probably rely heavily on `data.table` package, meaning I wouldn't need to declare any custom functions.

Comment: Additionally, in R, writing your own functions makes code more portable/reproducible because the functions can be held in a package: http://www.statmethods.net/interface/packages.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your initial questions:

1. I can't speak for R good practices in general - but I like
   functions, and I'm still reusing many of my functions created in my
   first R script. They also work well with parallelization.
2. You can use a range shorthand syntax such as `1:n` to create a range from 1 through `n`. Alternatively `seq(1, n)` would suffice in your use case.

Moreover:

1. Printing values generally isn't very useful. It doesn't work well with parallelization / vectorization. And in R studio, you can store values in variables and use them later; this wouldn't work with printing on the go.
2. Loop based approaches, in my experience, are quite slow. Consider using `lapply`.
3. I prefer `<-` over `=` just to remind me it's not `C`. (very highly subjective). When its not a top level assignment, e.g., named arguments, I use `=` due to the difference in scope.

Here's how I would write it. I've also included a parallel function, parallelization works quicker than lapply when `range` is sufficiently high. The code is supplemented with a mini benchmark, I've adjusted your for-loop code to be compatible, and inlined the integers 3 and 5 where appropriate.

```
# Run this once to install benchmark suite:
#install.packages(c("microbenchmark", "stringr"), dependencies = TRUE)
require(microbenchmark)
library(parallel)

# Setup parallelization particulars.
cores <- detectCores()
cluster <- makeCluster(cores)

gerardFizzBuzz <- function(i) {
    fizz <- i %% 3
    buzz <- i %% 5

    if (fizz == 0 & buzz == 0) {
      return('FizzBuzz')
    }
    else if (buzz == 0) {
      return('Buzz')
    }
    else if (fizz == 0) {
      return('Fizz')
    }

    return(i)
}

applyFizzBuzz <- function(range) {
    return(lapply(1:range, gerardFizzBuzz))
}

parallelFizzBuzz <- function(range) {
    return(parLapply(cluster, 1:range, gerardFizzBuzz))
}

vectorizedFizzBuzz <- function(range) {
    v <- Vectorize(gerardFizzBuzz)
    return(v(1:range))
}

papasmurfFizzBuzz <- function (range) {
    res <- seq(1, range)

    for (i in res){
      if (i %% 3 == 0 & i %% 5 == 0){
        res[i] <- 'FizzBuzz'
      }
      else if (i %% 5 ==0){
        res[i] <- 'Buzz'
      }
      else if (i %% 3 == 0){
        res[i] <- 'Fizz'
      }
      else{
        res[i] <- i
      }
    }

    return(res)
}

range <- 100000;

perf <- microbenchmark(applyFizzBuzz(range), vectorizedFizzBuzz(range), parallelFizzBuzz(range), papasmurfFizzBuzz(range), times=20)

# note the log scale.
boxplot(perf, names = c("lapply", "Vectorized", "parLapply", "forloop"))

stopCluster(cluster)
```

This is the result of running the above script on my machine (4 cores), with `range <- 100000` and `times=20`.
[image]

Comment: Some good stuff. Note that `lapply` is basically syntactic sugar for a `for` loop so it won't be faster. Rather than parallelization, the obvious faster implementation is to use vectorized operations on the whole `1:range` vector. Would make a nice addition to your benchmarks.

Comment: `lapply` is quicker than a `for` loop in this anecdotal test case, quite possibly indicative of more than just syntactic sugar? e.g., it may run via the underlying implementation without having round trips to the R run time. I can't speak for this. Vectorize is a wrapper around mapply, I'll add it to the script for reference.

Comment: @Gerard I really appreciate the answer, but 99% of what you said went way over my head at this point lol. However, the detail is wonderful and it's a great answer

Comment: I don't think you understand what I meant by vectorized. I mean to do all the operations in memory, using vectorized functions. Try `i <- 1:range; fizz <- i %% 3 == 0; buzz <- i %% 5 == 0; out <- as.character(i); out[ fizz & !buzz] <- 'Fizz'; out[!fizz &  buzz] <- 'Buzz'; out[ fizz &  buzz] <- 'FizzBuzz'; out`

Comment: Your `lapply` is faster than your `for` loop because your `lapply` code includes other implementation improvements (it stores `fizz` and `buzz`, it does not contain unnecessary data type conversions, etc.) See  this for example (http://stackoverflow.com/q/2275896/1201032) if you need more convincing, but don't get carried away by the statement that `lapply` can be a little faster than `for`, it is marginal. I can provide a better `for` implementation that will get close to your `lapply` if you insist.

Comment: @Gerard I'm going to go ahead and give you the bounty, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 11):

Just to add to @flodel's comments, here is a properly vectorized version. One can see this is quite a bit faster, outperforming the parallel option (on 7 cores) by a factor 5. This problem is a quite nice demonstration of why is is worth your time to think about vectorized code:

```
flodel_fizzbuzz <- function(range = 100, fizz = 3, buzz = 5) {
  s <- 1:range
  is.fizz <- s %% fizz == 0
  is.buzz <- s %% buzz == 0

  s[is.fizz] <- 'Fizz'
  s[is.buzz] <- 'Buzz'
  s[is.fizz & is.buzz] <- 'FizzBuzz'
  return(s)
}
```

Running the benchmarks from @Gerard's answer (note that `vectorizedFizzBuzz` isn't truly vectorized):

```
Unit: milliseconds
                      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
      applyFizzBuzz(range) 296.52224 303.19205 315.76901 309.18860 320.01676 384.18786    20   c 
 vectorizedFizzBuzz(range) 341.41121 356.82580 374.53857 362.45300 372.81459 461.65169    20    d
   parallelFizzBuzz(range) 117.40058 128.91812 158.66095 153.87976 170.76776 288.99613    20  b  
  papasmurfFizzBuzz(range) 292.22177 301.48002 316.31151 307.31605 319.05426 393.53235    20   c 
    flodel_fizzbuzz(range)  27.98101  29.15677  29.93554  29.93097  30.84586  32.09304    20 a
```

1. I do think functions are a nice way to perform these tasks.
2. The easiest way to create a range of subsequent integers is with `:`.

[image]

This `tidyverse` version does about equally well (with ~40 ms):

```
tidy_fizbuzz <- function(range = 100, fizz = 3, buzz = 5) {
  x <- 1:range
  dplyr::case_when(
    x %% (fizz * buzz) == 0 ~ "Fizz Buzz",
    x %% fizz == 0 ~ "Fizz",
    x %% buzz == 0 ~ "Buzz",
    TRUE ~ as.character(x)
  )
}
```